# ORACLE 12 C, cannot drop NOT NULL constraint on a DEFAULT ON NULL column

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

```
create table autos (
id integer generated by default on null as IDENTITY unique,
owner_name nvarchar2(50)
);
```

Then I insert in table several rows

```
insert into autos
(owner_name)
VALUES
('Nick');

insert into autos
(owner_name)
VALUES
('Tommy');
```

2 rows inserted, then for increase rows count, I run this query

```
insert into autos
(owner_name)
select owner_name
from autos;
```

Several query was run successfully, but after this, oracle returns error: `ORA-30667: cannot drop NOT NULL constraint on a DEFAULT ON NULL column`

Tell please, what is wrong here?

P.S. I use SQL Developer.

**UPDATE**

If I am trying all above codes in `sys` database connection, all works fine, but I am create new user (here is code how I create new user)

```
 CREATE USER C##OTO_USER
 IDENTIFIED BY oto_user_pass;

 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO C##OTO_USER;
```

Then I create new connection with `C##OTO_USER` and only in this connection happens above error.

Also, that error happens sometimes, sometimes `INSERT` query works fine.

And not only `INSERT... SELECT`, but usually `INSERT` statement also causes that error.

So, I think this is new user/connection problem, may be above user creating code, not creates complete user?

If trying inserting with SQL*PLUS, also same error happens.

Comment: the error message does not match your SQL statements

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I am also wonder, but when I am trying run `INSERT... SELECT` query, exactly this error message are returned.

Comment: This works fine for me on Oracle 12c and SQL Developer 3.2.20.09.  What happens if you run this code in SQL*Plus?  SQL*Plus is much more stable and predictable, running it there would tell us if this is a database issue or an IDE issue.

Comment: @ jonearles - please see update in my question.

Comment: Does the problem happen with local users, or just common users?  (I'm using 12c, but don't have container databases setup and don't have experience with that feature.)

Comment: Enable 10046 tracing and post the corresponding trace file

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you use IDENTITY in the column definition, you should take into account its restrictions.

If you want to insert rows as subquery so you encounter with following restriction: CREATE TABLE AS SELECT will not inherit the identity property on a column ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402)). Same situation happens with your insert, IDENTITY unique doesnt work properly.

```
  insert into autos
(owner_name)
select owner_name
from autos;
```